# The $\sigma$ - algebra generated by the nowhere dense subsets of a topological space

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I need to determine the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the nowhere dense subsets of a topological space.

Here is my attempt: I define the set of nowhere dense subsets as $\{A: (\overline A)^o= \emptyset \}$, $A \in X$, where $X$ is the topological space.

Let $S$ be the $\sigma$-algebra.

By the fact that $\sigma$-algebras are algebras, $\emptyset, X \in S$

Also, all nowhere dense subsets are in $S$, so $\{A: (\overline A)^o= \emptyset \} \in S$.

$S$ is closed under compliments, so $\{A^c: (\overline A)^o= \emptyset \} \in S$

But we have unions and intersections, and the finite unions of nowhere dense sets are still nowhere dense: $\{B \bigcup C: (\overline B)^o= \emptyset$ and $(\overline C)^o= \emptyset\} \subseteq \{A: (\overline A)^o= \emptyset \} \in S$.

Finite intersections of nowhere dense sets are either nowhere dense or empty: $\{B \bigcap C: (\overline B)^o= \emptyset$ and $(\overline C)^o= \emptyset\} = \emptyset \in S$ if $B \bigcap C = \emptyset$, or $\{B \bigcap C: (\overline B)^o= \emptyset$ and $(\overline C)^o= \emptyset\} \subseteq \{A: (\overline A)^o= \emptyset \} \in S$ if $B \bigcap C \neq \emptyset$.

Then we have finite intersections and unions of complements, which are easily sorted by the identities $(X\setminus A) \bigcup (X\setminus B) = X\setminus (A \bigcap B)$ and  $(X\setminus A) \bigcap (X\setminus B) = X\setminus (A \bigcup B)$.

The finite unions of nowhere dense sets and complements of nowhere dense sets are not nowhere dense, neither are they compliments of nowhere dense sets. So they are of a third type, and can be written $\{A \bigcup B^c: (\overline A)^o= \emptyset$ and $(\overline B)^o= \emptyset \} \in S$.

The finite intersections of nowhere dense sets and the compliments of nowhere dense sets should either be nowhere dense or empty, so they are of the first type or empty depending on if there is overlap.

Therefore, the $\sigma$-algebra $S = \{\emptyset, X\} \bigcup \{A: (\overline A)^o= \emptyset \} \bigcup \{A^c: (\overline A)^o= \emptyset \} \bigcup \{A \bigcup B^c: (\overline A)^o= \emptyset$ and $(\overline B)^o= \emptyset \}$.

I hope I didn't over-complicate this. Thank you for any feedback!

Comment: The $\sigma$-algebra needs to include also countable unions/intersections, those needn't be nowhere dense anymore.

Comment: A countable union of nowhere dense sets is called _meagre_ (also, a set of first category). A set is called _comeagre_ if its complement is meagre.